# Ruby: style and performance

Tags: ruby

**Note:** I don't know if this question should be in StackOverflow or CodeReview (StackExchange). If you think it should be in CodeReview, please tell me in the comments.

I have been playing with Ruby for a while now. I love Ruby because it is a very beautiful and expressive programming language. Lately, I have also been a bit obsessed with performance. It seems this obsession is making my Ruby code uglier. Here is a very simple example: a program that returns the ASCII range of a character (not considering accented characters or error handling).

I came up with eight solutions:

```rb
module MyProgram
  module Character
    UPPER_A = 65.freeze
    UPPER_Z = 90.freeze
    LOWER_A = 97.freeze
    LOWER_Z = 122.freeze

    module_function

    def ascii_range1(char)
      code = char.ord

      return [65, 90] if code.between?(65, 90)
      return [97, 122] if code.between?(97, 122)
    end

    def ascii_range2(char)
      code = char.ord

      if code.between?(65, 90)
        [65, 90]
      elsif code.between?(97, 122)
        [97, 122]
      end
    end

    def ascii_range3(char)
      code = char.ord

      return [65, 90] if code >= 65 && code <= 90
      return [97, 122] if code >= 97 && code <= 122
    end

    def ascii_range4(char)
      code = char.ord

      if code >= 65 && code <= 90
        [65, 90]
      elsif code >= 97 && code <= 122
        [97, 122]
      end
    end

    def ascii_range5(char)
      code = char.ord

      return [UPPER_A, UPPER_Z] if code.between?(UPPER_A, UPPER_Z)
      return [LOWER_A, LOWER_Z] if code.between?(LOWER_A, LOWER_Z)
    end

    def ascii_range6(char)
      code = char.ord

      if code.between?(UPPER_A, UPPER_Z)
        [UPPER_A, UPPER_Z]
      elsif code.between?(LOWER_A, LOWER_Z)
        [LOWER_A, LOWER_Z]
      end
    end

    def ascii_range7(char)
      code = char.ord

      return [UPPER_A, UPPER_Z] if code >= UPPER_A && code <= UPPER_Z
      return [LOWER_A, LOWER_Z] if code >= LOWER_A && code <= LOWER_Z
    end

    def ascii_range8(char)
      code = char.ord

      if code >= UPPER_A && code <= UPPER_Z
        [UPPER_A, UPPER_Z]
      elsif code >= LOWER_A && code <= LOWER_Z
        [LOWER_A, LOWER_Z]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

They all do the same thing and the differences are small... or so I thought. For example: the ugly expression `n >= a && n <= b` (not ugly in itself, just when compared to Ruby's `Comparable#between?`) is way faster than `n.between?(a, b)`.

Here are the benchmark results (using benchmark-ips):

```rb
Warming up --------------------------------------
                   1   134.374k i/100ms
                   2   150.861k i/100ms
                   3   215.836k i/100ms
                   4   222.775k i/100ms
                   5   150.204k i/100ms
                   6   152.013k i/100ms
                   7   220.250k i/100ms
                   8   218.256k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
                   1      2.432M (± 7.2%) i/s -     12.094M in   5.000927s
                   2      2.425M (± 6.9%) i/s -     12.069M in   5.005368s
                   3      4.142M (±11.4%) i/s -     20.504M in   5.019090s
                   4      4.442M (± 4.6%) i/s -     22.278M in   5.026760s
                   5      2.366M (± 3.0%) i/s -     11.866M in   5.019090s
                   6      2.367M (± 2.7%) i/s -     11.857M in   5.012120s
                   7      4.372M (± 3.4%) i/s -     22.025M in   5.043391s
                   8      4.367M (± 2.6%) i/s -     22.044M in   5.050882s

Comparison:
                   4:  4441965.7 i/s
                   7:  4372497.0 i/s - same-ish: difference falls within error
                   8:  4367421.3 i/s - same-ish: difference falls within error
                   3:  4141617.7 i/s - same-ish: difference falls within error
                   1:  2432164.3 i/s - 1.83x  slower
                   2:  2424708.2 i/s - 1.83x  slower
                   6:  2367435.3 i/s - 1.88x  slower
                   5:  2366400.6 i/s - 1.88x  slower
```

So it comes down to `ascii_range3`, `ascii_range4`, `ascii_range7` and `ascii_range8` (`ascii_range4` being the fastest) when what I really wanted was `ascii_range5` but faster. I don't find any of these four approaches as beautiful as `ascii_range5`, so I just pick the most efficient one (which normally is the ugliest one). This has been happening a lot to me lately and it is taking the beauty of my code. That bothers me.

Please, do not misunderstand the question: it is not about the most efficient way of solving this specific problem. It is about how to find a perfect balance between style and performance (and you can use this or any other example in your answer).

Thanks.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Do not start thinking about minor non-algorithmic performance boost unless you have tested the program and confirmed it is a significant main source of slowness. But if minor stuff like this matters for you, maybe you shouldn't even use Ruby.

Comment: @SOFe, you're right. Yesterday a very evil person tried to kill me. I attributed it to premature optimization. sPaGhEtTiCaSe, Code Review, most definitely, since you have a working solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how to find a perfect balance between style and performance

I completely agree with [@SOFe's sentiment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57070006/ruby-style-and-performance#comment100663873_57070006).

---

Basically what you should do is:

1. You write the most readable ("beautiful") code you can think of, which isn't obviously dumb.
2. If you notice that you have performance issues, you try to optimize your algorithm.
3. If there is no room for that kind of optimization, you try to make such micro-performance tradeoffs in the very limited area of the code where you have established you have a performance problem.

For the domains where Ruby is used, you never want to try to optimize without any evidence that the current solution is "too slow".

In real world scenarios, performance bottlenecks will rarely derive from CPU intensive usage. It's most commonly a suboptimal usage of databases/networking/various other I/O/etc.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby has a standard library which feels quite natural to use (for the most part). However, the library needs to jump through a lot of hoops to provide this natural experience.

The docs for `Comparable#between?` specify:

```
between?(min, max) → true or false

Returns false if obj <=> min is less than zero or if anObject <=> max is greater than zero, true otherwise.
```

Sounds like it's doing a lot more than `code >= UPPER_A && code <= UPPER_Z`. But why does it need to do all this extra stuff when all you want is to check whether a number is between A & B?

That extra stuff makes it possible for us to implement the following code:

```
1.between? 0, 100

'c'.between? 'a', 'z'

Date.parse("2019/06/31").between? Date.parse("2019/06/01"), Date.parse("2019/12/01")

Position.new("Manager").between? Position.new("Trainee"), Position.new("Director")
```

This implementation of `#between?` allows us to compare any type of object in an elegant, natural way. But of course, it's going to be slower than `code >= UPPER_A && code <= UPPER_Z`

So let's say you love the elegance of `1.compare?` but absolutely need the fastest performance possible? No problem. Just replace the method with your own implementation. You can reopen the class, `prepend` a module or use a refinement (and more). Eg.

```
class Integer
  def between?(a, b)
    self >= a && self <= b
  end
end
```